# Как дать роли базы данных MS SQL право на создание и изменение таблиц и других объекто?

Tags: sql, sql-server, администрирование

Всем привет! Возникла такая проблема: есть база данных с такой схемой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно создать 3 роли:

1. Полный доступ ко всем таблицам и выполнение представления;
2. Имеет полный доступ к таблицам groups и student, чтение только
   из таблицы rating и выполнение представления;
3. Чтение только из таблиц groups и student, полный доступ к таблице rating, полный
   запрет на представление.

Под полным доступом я подразумеваю запросы SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.

Роли я создал следующими скриптами:

1 роль:

```
use students
create role students_admin
grant select, insert, update on student to students_admin
grant select, insert, update on groups to students_admin
grant select, insert, update on rating to students_admin
grant select, insert, update on groups_info to students_admin
go
```

2 роль:

```
use students
create role students_editor1
grant select, insert, update, delete on student to students_editor1
grant select, insert, update, delete on groups to students_editor1
grant select on rating to students_editor1
grant select on groups_info to students_editor1
go
```

3 роль:

```
use students
create role students_editor2
grant select on student to students_editor2
grant select on groups to students_editor2
grant select, insert, update, delete on rating to students_editor2
go
```

Создал имена для входа, добавил в базу данных пользователей и включил их в нужные роли, проверил - всё работает. Но тут возникла проблема с выдачей первой роли больших прав (назовём роль админ).

Если дать админу просто право на создание таблицы

```
GRANT CREATE TO students_admin
```

то будет выдаваться ошибка, связанная со схемой dbo. Если дать разрешение на ALTER, то таблица создаваться будет, но прав на SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE у роли не будет. Вот собственно и вопрос - как через роли базы данных выдать права на создание, редактирование и удаление таблиц, а также встроенных функций и триггеров.

Версия SQL Server 13.0.5026.0 2016 Developer Edition

Answer (score 1):

Вроде разобрался, нужно было дать права на SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE на всю базу, а также права ALTER (для редактирования схемы dbo) и CREATE TABLE (для создания таблиц).